# Is there an easy way to link two objects property together?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

Using c# and winforms with .NET 4.5 I would like to link the `Checked` property of a menu item with the `Visible` property of a form.

Changing any of these two attribute would change the other one to keep them synchronized.

Is there an easy and elegant solution to do that ?

Comment: This is not an option for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this example with a checkbox and a button:

Wire up to the CheckedChanged event

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
        button1.Visible = !checkBox.Checked;
    }
```

**Edit:**

Ok, i misunderstood.

Although the solution of 'farid' is a clean solution with separation of concerns using viewmodel and model it also adds more complexity to your application.

If you don't want to use this mvvm pattern and put the logic in the code behind you can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to the form that has the visible property (or add a custom event), add a new Visible property that sets the base.visible property (inherited by the Form from the Control class) and raise the PropertyChanged event. in the form that contains the menu item you can wire up to the event and perform the necessary logic to set the checked state or do some other action.

Here is an example:

[image]

Form1 code behind:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    }

    private Form2 _frm2;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frm2 = new Form2();
        _frm2.MdiParent = this;
        _frm2.PropertyChanged += _frm2_PropertyChanged;
        _frm2.Show();
    }

    void _frm2_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Visible")
        {
            showToolStripMenuItem.Checked = _frm2.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void showToolStripMenuItem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

        if (_frm2 != null)
            _frm2.Visible = menuItem.Checked;
    }
}
```

Form2 code behind:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public new bool Visible
    {
        get 
        {
            return base.Visible; 
        }
        set
        {
            base.Visible = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Visible"));
        }
    }

    private void hideButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not enought because if the Visible property changes it won't update the Checked property of the menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows Forms Data Bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.90).aspx).

Every windows forms control has a `DataBindings` property that can be used to bind a property in given data source to one of controls properties.

You can structure your code like example below:

This example shows binding from a `ViewModel` object to a control property. In your specific case you can bind a `ViewModel` property to two control property.

```
public partial class StackOverflowForm : Form
{
        public ViewModel Model { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Control> BindableControls { get; set; }
        public StackOverflowForm()
        {
            Model = new ViewModel();
            Model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
            BindableControls = new Dictionary<string, Control>();
            Model.Visible = false;
            InitializeComponent();
            RegisterBinding(boundButton, "Visible", Model, "Visible");
        }

        void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in BindableControls)
            {
                NotifyChange(item.Value, e.PropertyName);
            }
        }

        private void NotifyChange(Control control, string propertyName)
        {
            button1.DataBindings[propertyName].ReadValue();
        }

        private void RegisterBinding(Control control, string controlPropertyName, ViewModel _model, string modelPropertyName)
        {
            control.DataBindings.Add(controlPropertyName, _model, modelPropertyName, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            BindableControls[control.Name] = control;
        }
        private void SetPropertyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Model.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _IsVisible;
        public bool Visible
        {
            get
            {
                return _IsVisible;
            }
            set
            {
                _IsVisible = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Visible"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

I have defined a ViewModel object in the form that is used as binding data source for controls. (that have a Visible property)

```
private void RegisterBinding(Control control, string controlPropertyName, ViewModel _model, string modelPropertyName)
 {
     control.DataBindings.Add(controlPropertyName, _model, modelPropertyName, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            BindableControls[control.Name] = control;
 }
```

Use `RegisterBinding` method to register simple binding (parameters are simple enough).

'ViewModel' class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in `System.ComponentModel`. This interface adds a `PropertyChanged` event to call when any property in ViewModel changes.

In form's constructor I added event listener to `PropertyChanged` event of `ViewModel` in listener I forced the binding to read new value for each of controls that a binding registered for it. This portion of code refresh's the bound control and changes the visible state of button.

**NOTE:** In order to answer simplicity I assumed that properties in `ViewModel` that bound to a control's property has SAME name with destination property in form control. (Mode.Visible and boundButton.Visible). If you want to implement property name mapping for source and destination properties you can use a `Dictionary` or something to achieve this functionality.

Comment: This is a solution which is seems complex, and not really elegant. But it will work :-)